# Decode json object in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a json file and reading it and decode it as follows.
my json file looks like as follows, A and B represents the struct object. I wonder are there a better and effective way to decoding this type of json?

```
[ 
 [
   {"id": "152478", "age": "20"},{"character": "king", "isDead":"no", "canMove" :"yes"}
 ],
 [
  {"id": "887541", "age": "22"},{"character": "lion", "isDead":"no", "canMove" :"yes"}
 ]
]
```

decoding is as follows:

```
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mypew", withExtension: "json")!
        do {

        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)

         // B -> json[0][0], [1][0]
         // A -> json[0][1], [0][1]

        response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! [[[String: Any]]]
        for i in 0..<response.count
        {
            for j in 0..<response[i].count
            {
                if j == 0
                {
                    let jsonDat = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:response[i][j]))!
                    let bElement = try JSONDecoder().decode(B.self, from: jsonDat)
                    self.bArray.append(bElement)
                }
                else if j == 1
                {
                    let jsonDatt = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:response[i][j]))!
                    let aElement = try JSONDecoder().decode(A.self, from: jsonDatt)
                    self.aArray.append(aElement)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you want the end result to look like? If I understood your code correctly, looks like you want 2 separate arrays? Or is there some struct that holds a pair?

Comment: I am going to display this information in the custom table view cell. Yes each array item holds 2 json objects.

Comment: Do you mean, you want something like `struct Pair { let a: A; let b: B }`, and array of those?

Comment: Yes, I want to have it that way if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the two objects (let's call them `A` and `B`) conform to `Decodable`:

```
struct A: Decodable {
    var id, age: String
}

struct B: Decodable {
    var character, isDead, canMove: String
}
```

Then, if your structure for the pair of `A` and `B` is always the same, i.e. it's always `[A, B]`, then you can decode the pair into its own object. Let's call that object `ABPair`:

```
struct ABPair: Decodable {
  let a: A
  let b: B

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

    guard let a = try? container.decode(A.self), 
          let b = try? container.decode(B.self) 
      else {
        // throw since we didn't find A first, followed by B
        throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "error")
      }

    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  }
}
```

And you can decode the array of pairs as follows:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let pairs = try? decoder.decode([ABPair].self, from: jsonData)
```

```swift
print(pairs[1].b.character) // lion
```

Comment: I am getting Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'container' is immutable in the ABPAir Struct in the guard statement, any idea?

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please check the following question it is follow up on that solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336022/swift-decode-composite-struct-data

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, you need to create a `Codable` struct for the model. Then decode the model from the data and not the JSON object. Here the code,

Model:

```
struct Model: Codable {
    let id, age, character, isDead, canMove: String?
}
```

Decoding:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mypew", withExtension: "json")!
do {
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let models = try JSONDecoder().decode([[Model]].self, from: jsonData)
    for model in models {
        print(model[0].age, model[1].canMove)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: then how do you print out `canMove` and `age`, since both are located in the different object?

Comment: The JSON structure is a bit strange, so you should provide the array index to get the value of properties, like this `print(response[0][0].age, response[0][1].canMove)`. Maybe you should ask the backend to modify this JSON model.